# Please review close votes!

Tags: discussion, voting-to-close

There are currently 261 questions waiting for [review](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review), as far as I could tell. Maybe my guess is off a little, but it seems consistent with 270 on the orange bar.

**There are many of us who can vote!** About 68 as far as I can tell, and we only need 5 to 9 votes to get question out of the queue. So please, please vote. Click "leave open" if you feel like, click "close" if you think question is bad, but let's purge this queue!

Comment: If we don't know what this means...is that because we're not eligible to vote? Is there a url to look at to review things?

Comment: @greggles You need a reputation of 3000, to vote to close questions; see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/694. (I guess you should be able to see that page.)

Comment: @greggles, the review links are under review, up at the top bar next to your user rep and badges. Also next to the help link and the search bar.

Comment: *phew* I've maxed out my close votes three days in a row now. The queue just barely appears to be shrinking. :/ On a positive note I guess this means I'll be approaching a gold reviewer badge soon ;)

Comment: @Letharion To get something out, we need 5 votes to close or 5 votes to leave open. So  9 people actively voting would be enough. Seems there simply is not enough of us :( Anyway, have fun earning your [Steward](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/102/steward) badge!